# Does CSS ever care about DOM "closeness" relationships?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity, css-cascade

Given the following code:

```css
div, span {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.light-background {
  background-color: #cacaca;
}

.dark-background {
  background-color: #333;
}

.dark-background span {
  color: white;
}

.light-background span {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="light-background">
  <div class="dark-background">
    <span>Here is some light text on a dark background.</span>
    
    <div class="light-background">
      <span>Here is some dark text on a light background.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>Here is some dark text on a light background.</span>
</div>
```

The inner-most span matches both `.dark-background span` as well as `.light-background span`, so there seems to only ever be a relationship to the CSS cascade weight and the last-rule-defined cascade, and never how close the two selectors in a rule are to each other in the HTML.

Is it possible to apply a rule if the elements matched by the selector are closer to each other than other rules which may match?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `>` or `~` in a selector? But no, no specific selector for a "close" element

Comment: you firt need to define "closeness". For me both are closely equal

Comment: By "closeness" I mean more directly-descendant. E.g., the span which does not follow the rule (the first span) has a hierarchy in DOM as `.light-background .dark-background span`, but although the "closest" html structure is `.dark-background span`, this is ignored because the selector `.light-background span` is defined after `.dark-background span`

Comment: `directly-descendant` is this selector `>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before addressing your question, which is a high-level question about selector matching in general, let's get your actual problem out of the way. All you're really trying to do is style each `span` based on whether its parent is a `.light-background` or a `.dark-background`, and the solution for the problem in your CSS is simply to replace the descendant combinator with the child combinator:

```css
.dark-background > span {
  color: white;
}

.light-background > span {
  color: black;
}
```

```css
div, span {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.light-background {
  background-color: #cacaca;
}

.dark-background {
  background-color: #333;
}

.dark-background > span {
  color: white;
}

.light-background > span {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="light-background">
  <div class="dark-background">
    <span>Here is some light text on a dark background.</span>
    
    <div class="light-background">
      <span>Here is some dark text on a light background.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>Here is some dark text on a light background.</span>
</div>
```

With that out of the way, why does your approach with descendant selectors not work as expected to begin with? That's where we turn to your question:

> Does CSS ever care about DOM “closeness” relationships?

No, complex selectors matching the same element are compared only by specificity. And specificity does not take into account the proximity of the elements matched by each compound selector, because this requires information about the DOM, and specificity is *never* calculated based on any information about the DOM. Likewise, combinators themselves do not contribute to specificity.

Given the following example:

```
<div class="A">
  <div class="B">
    <div class="C"></div>
    <div class="D"></div>
    <div class="E"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In each of these pairs, both selectors match the same element and are equally specific; therefore the second rule will always take precedence over the first:

```
.B .C   {}
.B > .C {}

.B > .C {}
.B .C   {}

.A .C   {}
.B .C   {}

.B .C   {}
.A .C   {}

.D ~ .E {}
.D + .E {}

.D + .E {}
.D ~ .E {}

.C ~ .E {}
.D ~ .E {}

.D ~ .E {}
.C ~ .E {}
```

> Is it possible to apply a rule if the elements matched by the selector are closer to each other than other rules which may match?

No, this is currently not possible. css-values-3 has a proposed feature called `toggle()` that will aid in solving problems that are somewhat similar to yours but not quite the same. But there hasn't been any interest in implementing it for the last several years, so it's been punted to level 4, and I don't expect implementations to surface for at least the next 5 years.

Comment: Saying 'XY problem' is a Z problem. Let's not parrot this obtuseness.

Comment: @Jan Kyu Peblik: I'd considered ignoring the example altogether and addressing the question on its own merits, but I figured there's a reason they included their example, however detached it was from their question. I can remove my statement calling this an XY problem, but it still wouldn't change the nature of the question, or my answer as it now stands.

Comment: It would change the inclusion of that bit of nonsense in your question, which would be great.

Comment: @Jan Kyu Peblik: OK, I've removed it.

Comment: Appreciated. 21

Comment: @BoltClock - Excellent excellent answer. One of the best I've seen on SO and exactly the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you re-order the declarations, you'll see the text-color change. Later definitions override sooner ones.

You can use the `>` operator to restrict your selection somewhat `#main > span` will match only spans immediately beneath `#main`, the `+` selector selects the next-sibling in the dom. & you've got `nth-child` in/around that type of selection. Is that what you meant by:

> Is it possible to apply a rule if the elements matched by the selector are closer to each other than other rules which may match?

```css
div, span {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.light-background {
  background-color: #cacaca;
}

.dark-background {
  background-color: #333;
}

.light-background span {
  color: black;
}

.dark-background span {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="light-background">
  <div class="dark-background">
    <span>Here is some light text on a dark background.</span>
    
    <div class="light-background">
      <span>Here is some dark text on a light background.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span>Here is some dark text on a light background.</span>
</div>
```